# Не выводит в csv файл метрические характеристики семечек

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, pycharm

Сначала программа поворачивает изображение обрезает и сохраняет в цикле набор изображений в цикле в папку `output_folder`. Потом идёт циклическая обработка изображений этой папки-создаётся набор матриц с 0 и 1 где на пикселе `r,g,b<115,115,115` там 1, а в противном случаи 0. Далее нахождение сумм столбцов матриц и находить максимальные по сумме их столбцы в цикле.Также их индексы аналогичные действия необходимо проводить и с строками матриц.В строках с максимальными суммами находить минимальные и максимальные значения индексов столбцов со значениями матрицы 1. и аналогические действия проводятся со столбцами. По кординатам окраин длин и ширин изображений находим точки их пересечения. Потом нужно высчитать части длинн и части ширин до и точек их пересечениях.
Далее необходимо найти характеристики формы указанные внизу программы. Изображения семечек прилагаются [![семечка из директории SeedsBela][1]][1]  [![семечка из директории SeedsBela][2]] [2] [![семечка из директории SeedsBela][3]][3] [![семечка из директории SeedsBela][4]][4]
Код:

```
import csv
    import numpy as np
    from PIL import Image  # Подключим необходимые библиотеки.
    import cv2
    import math
    import time
    import os
    from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
    def main():
      input_folder = "SeedsBela"
      output_folder = "RotateCropImages"
    
    # Создаем выходную папку, если ее еще нет
      if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
        os.makedirs(output_folder)
    
    # Получаем список файлов в папке с изображениями
      image_files = [f for f in os.listdir(input_folder) if f.endswith(('.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg'))]
    
    # Указываем угол поворота и обрезку
      rotation_angle = 315
      crop_box = (250, 188, 1248, 883)  # (left, top, right, bottom)
    
      for image_file in image_files:
        input_path = os.path.join(input_folder, image_file)
        output_path = os.path.join(output_folder, image_file)
    
        # Открываем изображение
        with Image.open(input_path) as img:
            # Поворачиваем изображение
            rotated_img = img.rotate(rotation_angle)
    
            # Обрезаем изображение
            cropped_img = rotated_img.crop(crop_box)
    
            # Сохраняем результат
            cropped_img.save(output_path)
    
    
    
      tp1 = time.time()
    
      images = []
      for filename in os.listdir(output_folder):
          file_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(output_folder, filename))
          if os.path.isfile(file_path):
              images.append(file_path)
    
      p = Pool(processes=4)
      results = p.map(process_image, images)
      p.close()
      p.join()
    
      tp2 = time.time()
      print(f'*** Общее время: {tp2 - tp1} ***')
    
    def process_image(path):
      print(f'*** Изображение: {path} ***')
          # ----------------------------------------
          # Строки 41 - 47. Преобразование фотографии в матрицу нулей и едениц
      image = cv2.imread(path)
      r, g, b = cv2.split(image)
      bit_matrix_r = (r < 115)
      bit_matrix_g = (g < 115)
      bit_matrix_b = (b < 115)
      bit_matrix = np.multiply(np.multiply(bit_matrix_r, bit_matrix_g), bit_matrix_b)
      numb_matrix = bit_matrix.astype(int)
      for row in numb_matrix:
          # row Переменная для хранения
          # максимальной суммы строки.
          max_row = 0
          # Переменная для хранения
          # индекса строки с максимальной суммой.
          id_row = 0
          # индекс текущей строки
          i = 0
         # для каждой строки в матрице ...
    
          # сумму элементов переданного ей списка.
          # Если сумма элементов строки
          # больше значения max_row,
          if sum(row) > max_row:  # Функция sum() возвращает
              # то присвоить переменной max_row эту сумму,
              max_row = sum(row)
              # а в id_row сохранить индекс этой строки.
              id_row = i
          # увеличить индекс на 1
          i += 1
    
      # Переменная для хранения
      # максимальной суммы столбца.
      max_col = 0
      # Переменная для хранения
      # индекса столбца с максимальной суммой.
      id_col = 0
      # перебор индексов столбцов
      for i in range(len(numb_matrix)):
          # сумма текущего столбца
          col_sum = 0
          # перебор индексов строк
          for j in range(len(numb_matrix)):
              # Извлекается очередной элемент столбца,
              # и добавляется к col_sum,
              # при этом изменяется индекс строк (j),
              # индекс столбца неизменен (i).
              col_sum += numb_matrix[j][i]
              # Если сумма элементов текущего столбца
              # больше значения max_col,
              if col_sum > max_col:
                  # то записать значение
                  # первой переменной в вторую,
                  max_col = col_sum
                  # а индекс столбца сохранить в id_col.
                  id_col = i
              # вывод индекса столбца и его суммы
              #print(id_col, '-', max_col)
              height_s = sum(numb_matrix[id_col])  # Ширина семечки
              width_s = sum(numb_matrix[id_row])  # Длинна семечки
              stroka = np.array(numb_matrix[id_row])#Значения матрицы по ширине семечки
              stolbec = np.array(numb_matrix[id_col])#Значения матрицы по длинне семечки
    
      for i in range(len(stroka)):  # Столбцы строки с максимальной суммой со значением 1
          if (stroka[i] == 1):
              index_stroka_element = np.array(i)  # Вывод номеров столбцов строки с максимальной суммой со значением 1
    
      for i in range(len(stolbec)):  # Строки столбца с максимальной суммой со значением 1
          if (stolbec[i] == 1):
              index_stolbec_element = np.array(i)  # Преобразование в массив номеров строк столбца с максимальной суммой со значением 1
              max_X = + index_stroka_element  # Максимальная координата Y строки с максимальной суммой
              max_Y = + index_stolbec_element  # Максимальная координата X столбца с максимальной суммой
              min_x = max_X - width_s + 1  # Минимальная координата Y строки с максимальной суммой
              min_y = max_Y - height_s  # Минимальная координата X столбца с максимальной суммой
              L_1 = [[id_row, min_x], [id_row, max_X]]  # Координаты начала и конца линии по длинне семечки
              L_2 = [[min_y, id_col], [max_Y, id_col]]  # Координаты начала и конца линии по ширине семечки
    
      xd = (L_1[0][0] - L_1[1][0], L_2[0][0] - L_2[1][0])
      yd = (L_1[0][1] - L_1[1][1], L_2[0][1] - L_2[1][1])
    
      div = xd[0] * yd[1] - xd[1] * yd[0]
    
      if div == 0:
          raise Exception('lines do not intersect')
    
      d = (L_1[0][0] * L_1[1][1] - L_1[0][1] * L_1[1][0], L_2[0][0] * L_2[1][1] - L_2[0][1] * L_2[1][0])
      x = (d[0] * xd[1] - d[1] * xd[0]) / div  # Кооордината пересечения по x
      y = (d[0] * yd[1] - d[1] * yd[0]) / div  # Кооордината пересечения по y
      lineA = y - min_x  # Часть ширина семечки до центра
      lineB = max_X - y  # Часть ширины от центра до края
      lineC = max_X - x  # Часть длины семечки до центра
      lineD = x - min_y  # Часть длины семечки от центра к краю
      rs1 = lineA * lineC / 2  # Площадь 1 трикутника
      rs2 = lineC * lineB / 2  # Площадь 2 трикутника
      rs3 = lineA * lineD / 2  # Площадь 3 трикутника
      rs4 = lineB * lineD / 2  # Площадь 4 трикутника
      romb = rs1 + rs2 + rs3 + rs4 # Площадь ромба ,состоящего из этих треугольников
      R_Proportion1 = rs1 / romb# Часть площади в 1 секторе
      R_Proportion2 = rs2 / romb# Часть площади в 2 секторе
      R_Proportion3 = rs3 / romb# Часть площади в 3 секторе
      R_Proportion4 = rs4 / romb# Часть площади в 4 секторе
      square = 0
      for i in range(len(numb_matrix)):
          for j in range(len(numb_matrix[i])):
              square += numb_matrix[i][j]#Площадь всего изображения семечки
      square1 = square * R_Proportion1# Площадь 1-го сектора семечки
      square2 = square * R_Proportion2# Площадь 2-го сектора семечки
      square3 = square * R_Proportion3# Площадь 3-го сектора семечки
      square4 = square * R_Proportion4# Площадь 4-го сектора семечки
      S_Dug1 = rs1 - square1# Площадь 1-го сектора семечки вне треугольнитка
      S_Dug2 = rs2 - square2# Площадь 2-го сектора семечки вне треугольнитка
      S_Dug3 = rs3 - square3# Площадь 3-го сектора семечки вне треугольнитка
      S_Dug4 = rs4 - square4# Площадь 4-го сектора семечки вне треугольнитка
    
      hip1 = math.sqrt(lineA ** 2 + lineC ** 2)#Гипотенуза 1 треугольника
      hip2 = math.sqrt(lineC ** 2 + lineB ** 2)#Гипотенуза 2 треугольника
      hip3 = math.sqrt(lineA ** 2 + lineD ** 2)#Гипотенуза 3 треугольника
      hip4 = math.sqrt(lineB ** 2 + lineD ** 2)#Гипотенуза 4 треугольника
    
      beta1 = math.asin(lineC / hip1)# Первал половина 1 угла
      beta2 = math.asin(lineC / hip2)# Первал половина 3 угла
      beta3 = math.asin(lineD / hip3)# Вторая половина 3 угла
      beta4 = math.asin(lineD / hip4)# Вторая половина 1 угла
    
      alpha1 = 90 - beta1# Первал половина 2 угла
      alpha2 = 90 - beta2# Первал половина 4 угла
      alpha3 = 90 - beta3# Вторая половина 4 угла
      alpha4 = 90 - beta4# Вторая половина 2 угла
    
      firstAngle = beta1 + beta4#Первый угол
      secondAngle = alpha1 + alpha2#Второй укол
      thirdAngle = beta2 + beta3#Третий угол
      fourthAngle = alpha1 + alpha4#Четвёртый угол
      zol = (lineA + lineB) / (lineC + lineD)#Отношения  длинны и ширины
      with open('BlackSeedsBelka.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
          fieldnames = ['Name', 'lineA', 'lineB', 'lineC', 'lineD', 'firstAngle', 'secondAngle', 'thirdAngle',
                        'fourthAngle',
                        'square', 'S_Dug1', 'S_Dug2', 'S_Dug3', 'S_Dug4', 'zol']
          writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    
          writer.writeheader()
          writer.writerow({'Name': path, 'lineA': lineA, 'lineB': lineB, 'lineC': lineC, 'lineD': lineD,
                           'firstAngle': firstAngle, 'secondAngle': secondAngle, 'thirdAngle': thirdAngle,
                           'fourthAngle': fourthAngle, 'square': square, 'S_Dug1': S_Dug1, 'S_Dug2': S_Dug2,
                           'S_Dug3': S_Dug3,
                           'S_Dug4': S_Dug4, 'zol': zol})
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

**Результат работы программы:**

> multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback:  """ Traceback (most recent call
> last):   File "C:\Program
> Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py",
> line 121, in worker
> result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py",
> line 44, in mapstar
> return list(map(*args))   File "E:\CentrCicleImages\main.py", line 136, in process_image
> xd = (L_1[0][0] - L_1[1][0], L_2[0][0] - L_2[1][0]) UnboundLocalError: local variable 'L_1' referenced before assignment
> """
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "E:\CentrCicleImages\main.py", line 206, in 
> main()   File "E:\CentrCicleImages\main.py", line 50, in main
> results = p.map(process_image, images)   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py",
> line 268, in map
> return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()   File "C:\Program
> Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py",
> line 657, in get
> raise self._value UnboundLocalError: local variable 'L_1' referenced before assignment
>
> Process finished with exit code 1